# Reading and printing a file in C

Tags: c

Ok, I'm trying to read in a text file with my information. The text file contents is this:

**gasData.txt**

```
0 987654 201200 4.000000
1 red 89114 0.000000
2 red 89712 13.500000
3 red 90229 15.300000
4 987654 201001 0.000000
5 987654 201111 5.200000
6 987654 201612 25.299999
7 red 89300 7.100000
8 green 16 0.000000
9 green 216 20.000000
10 green 518 61.000000
11 green 879 50.000000
```

**CODE**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define N 12

struct record
{
    char id[7];
    int odometer;
    float gallons;
};
typedef struct record record_t;

record_t gasData[N];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    FILE *fileInput;
    float gallons;
    int element;
    char id[10], odometer[10];

    fileInput = fopen("gasData.txt", "r");

    for(element = 0; element < N; element++)
    {
        fscanf(fileInput, "%s %s %f", id, odometer, &gallons);

        /*if (feof(fileInput))
        {
            printf("end-of-file detected on file in\n");
            exit(1);
        }*/

        printf("element = %d:, id = %s, odometer = %s, gallons = %f\n", element, id, odometer, gallons);
    }

    exit (0);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
element = 0:, id = (, odometer = ₧j↑u►↓@, gallons = 0.000000
element = 1:, id = (, odometer = ₧j↑u►↓@, gallons = 0.000000
element = 2:, id = (, odometer = ₧j↑u►↓@, gallons = 0.000000
element = 3:, id = (, odometer = ₧j↑u►↓@, gallons = 0.000000
element = 4:, id = (, odometer = ₧j↑u►↓@, gallons = 0.000000
element = 5:, id = (, odometer = ₧j↑u►↓@, gallons = 0.000000
element = 6:, id = (, odometer = ₧j↑u►↓@, gallons = 0.000000
element = 7:, id = (, odometer = ₧j↑u►↓@, gallons = 0.000000
element = 8:, id = (, odometer = ₧j↑u►↓@, gallons = 0.000000
element = 9:, id = (, odometer = ₧j↑u►↓@, gallons = 0.000000
element = 10:, id = (, odometer = ₧j↑u►↓@, gallons = 0.000000
element = 11:, id = (, odometer = ₧j↑u►↓@, gallons = 0.000000
```

What I'm getting out is nonsense, here is my output from the program. The only thing that works is the element, but that's just the count of the loop, so no problem there. Also, when I uncomment my end-of-file loop, my program crashes. Sorry I don't know how to edit the list. Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDITED CODE**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define N 12

/*struct record
{
    char id[7];
    int odometer;
    float gallons;
};
typedef struct record record_t;

record_t gasData[N];*/

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    FILE *fileInput;
    float gallons;
    int element;
    char id[10]; char odometer[10];

    fileInput = fopen("gasData.txt", "r");
    if (fileInput == NULL)
        return -1;

    for(element = 0; element < N; element++)
    {
        if (fscanf(fileInput, "%9s%9s%f", id, odometer, &gallons) == 3)
        {
            printf("element = %d:, id = %s, odometer = %s, gallons = %f\n",
                element, id, odometer, gallons);
        }
    }

    exit (0);
}
```

Comment: Do the input file contain three fields or four? And why are you reading the "odometer" field as a string if it's a number?

Comment: ok, posted the new code with the changes. I'm getting a -1 so my open file is not working correctly. Sorry, I usually program in C++ so I'm not use to the C language all that well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely overflowing the buffers and overwrinting the `'\0'` terminator try this

```
fscanf(fileInput, "%9s%9s%f", id, odometer, &gallons);
```

and also, check that `fscanf()` did succeed, otherwise the values will be uninitialized and the same thing will happen so

```
if (fscanf(fileInput, "%9s%9s%f", id, odometer, &gallons) == 3)
{
    printf("element = %d:, id = %s, odometer = %s, gallons = %f\n", 
        element, id, odometer, gallons);
}
```

don't assume that things are going to go fine, also check that `fopen()` didn't fail

```
fileInput = fopen("gasData.txt", "r");
if (fileInput == NULL)
    return -1;
```

This code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define N 12

struct record
{
    char id[7];
    int odometer;
    float gallons;
};
typedef struct record record_t;

record_t gasData[N];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    FILE *fileInput;
    float gallons;
    int   element;
    char  id[10];
    char  odometer[10];

    fileInput = fopen("gasData.txt", "r");
    if (fileInput == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open `gasData.txt'\n");
        return -1;
    }
    for(element = 0; element < N; element++)
    {
        if (fscanf(fileInput, "%9s%9s%f", id, odometer, &gallons) == 3)
        {
            printf("element = %d:, id = %s, odometer = %s, gallons = %f\n",
                element, id, odometer, gallons);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

should not fail.

Comment: tested your method, getting same result

Comment: @JohnnyAndrea do not modify the question, add an edited code if you want, but now you invalidated my answer.

Comment: sorry, ill change it back real quick.

Comment: @JohnnyAndrea I teseted the posted code and it works.

Comment: Ok, I've tested you code. For some reason, I still can't open gasData.txt. Do you know what would cause this on my system, but not yours? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

After incorporating @ihorob's solution, I got the a working code.

Thanks a lot.

Addition:

Remove the `#include <unistd.h>`, it is not required in this example and causes doubt in its relavence to Windows OS.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 12

struct record
{
    char id[7];
    int odometer;
    float gallons;
};
typedef struct record record_t;

record_t gasData[N];

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    float gallons = 0.0;
    int element = 0;
    char id[10] = { 0 }, odometer[10] = { 0 };
    FILE *fileInput = fopen("gasData.txt", "r");
    if (fileInput == NULL)
        return -1;
    for (element = 0; element < N; element++)
        if (fscanf(fileInput, "%9s%9s%f", id, odometer, &gallons) == 3)
            printf("element = %d:, id = %s, odometer = %s, gallons = %f\n", element, id, odometer, gallons);

    return(0);
}
```